# Crontab to run git pull as www-data user

Tags: git, ubuntu, cron

I've created cronjob with `crontab -u www-data -e` and added the following command:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme && /usr/local/bin/git pull origin dev
```

But it's not pulling in anything. I've also set up custom cron log via rsyslog, but it only shows command, no output. When I run said command as root everything works.

Permissions on dirs and files are setup properly, and owner of said directory is www-data.

Comment: Did you try running the command using `sudo`? Maybe the user `www-data` does not have the credentials to access the remote repository.

Comment: so what happens when you run said command as `www-data` rather than as `root`? when debugging commands run be cron it often helps to wrap everything into a single shell-script and call that (and ad lib debugging printout).

Comment: At the very least the proposed duplicate should help you articulate a well-formed question about `cron` problems. If you still need help, please  [edit] your question to provide the customary troubleshooting details, starting with any error message delivered to your (or `www-data`'s) email.

Comment: add `>> /temp/myjob.log 2>&1` for quick and dirty debugging. +1 on the "wrap all actions in single script with adequate logging" suggestion